# Excel: Sumifs multiple date criteria

Tags: excel, date

I'm trying to sum payments, paid within a year of the start date but my sumifs functions doesn't seem to work as desired. Any idea what needs to be tweaked?

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C11,B2:B11,">="&I3,B2:B11,"<="&K3,D2:D11,">="&B2:B11,D2:D11,"<="&E2:E11)
```

Excel Data:

[image: Excel Data]

Comment: the problem is with `D2:D11,">="&B2:B11,D2:D11,"<="&E2:E11`  you cannot have an array as the criteria.  ou may need to move to SUMPRODUCT() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$11*($B$2:$B$11>=I3)*($B$2:$B$11<=K3)*($D$2:$D$11>=$B$2:$B$11)*($D$2:$D$11<=$E$2:$E$11))
```

The SUMPRODUCT, will iterate through the range and do the comparisons.  If all the Boolean arguments resolve to true then the value of C at that row will be added.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.